# route to VPN network

Tags: vpn, routing

I have a VPN question and hope there is an answer in the ether. :-) 
My setup so far: (layer 3)

OpenVPN Server: NIC `eth0 10.85.202.20`

```
tun
topology subnet
server 10.10.16.0 255.255.240.0
route 172.16.0.0 255.240.0.0
client-to-client
#TLS stuff ...
```

Now my clients are not only one machine, but routers with their dedicated network:

```
172.16.2.0/24
172.16.3.0/24
172.16.4.0/24
...
172.16.8.0/24
...
```

and devices in that network.

I'm setting up clients (routers)

```
tun
port 1194
datacom.domain.de
10.10.16.0
255.255.240.0
...
```

and push the route via ccd-files (example)

```
iroute 172.16.8.0 255.255.255.0
```

From the OpenVPN-Server I do have access to the routers `ping 172.16.8.1` 
and to all the devices in the networks `nmap -sn 172.16.8.0/24` 
All network traffic of the client networks is going trough local wan/nic 
I also have a Win10 client, I can connect to the OpenVPN Server and then this machine does have access to all the networks connected to the server and all the services in that networks. (web-gui, ssh, ftp, ... to the devices)
Inside these networks there is no route set up into parallel networks.
`ping 172.16.20.1` inside 172.16.8.0/24 is not possible.

Works as designed!

Now to the question:
I do have a win11 machine in same local network as the OpenVPN server NIC `eth0 10.85.202.30` and I want to give this machine same access like it would have with logging in as a client onto the VPN.

`route add -p 172.16.0.0 mask 255.240.0.0 10.85.202.20 if 24`

How do I set up the OpenVPN-Server to route this from eth0 to tun0?

I did try:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

Goal is to USE an OpenVPN Client on this Win11 to access an OpenVPN Server on 172.16.8.1:1194 with tap (layer 2) to easily move it virtualy inside the 172.16.8.0/24 network. (for Boadcast, IGMP, ...)

Is this the way to go?
How else could I accive the goal?

tunnel trough tunnel?
tap on client-router?

Best regards.

Comment: My apologies, it was my first question and I am not familiar with the etiquette here.

The system as described works as designed, I just set the wrong IP of the OpenVPN server.

Can I leave the "question" in there as it is, in case someone has a similar problem and use this as a template?

VPN Setup, VPN Routing, Network routing.

Have fun with it.

Comment: Just answer your own question with the solution you found, and mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The system as described works as designed,
I just set the wrong IP of the OpenVPN server in the route add of the client.

routing eth0 to tun0 is working